# Elasticsearch documents present but not available in search?

Tags: elasticsearch

You have a small cluster, running ES 8.9.1 on 6 nodes.

A document gets inserted, everything seems to work; by looking directly at the document ES returns it:

`GET /<index>/<doc_id>`

and you get the document which is something like:

```
{ "_index": "<INDEX_NAME>", 
  "_id": "<DOC_ID>", 
  "_version": 7,
  "_seq_no": 84916,
  "_primary_term": 14,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
     (some fields here)
     "priority": 2, 
     (more fields here)
    }
}
```

now, I need to find the document (I'm simplifying -- we're not really using the lucene syntax):

`GET /<index>/_search?q=priority:2`

and I'm getting a few other results, **but not the previously inserted document**, although it is in the index -- I feel I'm missing something obvious here. Besides, document availability seems to be fluctuating. Sometimes found documents disappear again. All nodes are apparently working fine and there are no errors reported.

a `POST /<index>/_refresh` resulted in no appreciable improvement.

Comment: When you are doing search - any documents returned? Do you have documents with same priority in index? May be your document just not in first 20 results (if you are on default `size` value)?

Comment: Yea, other docs are returned; realised the `size` issue shortly after I posted and ran a few more tests, apparently the doc just szeems not to be findable; after a rolling restart of the cluster everything seems to be back to normal and search results appear more consistent (which begs the question: besides these 'glitches' after a few days nodes' performance decreases sharply and I start to see memory problems/circuit breaking exceptions -- is it sane to setup an automatic rolling restart via cron on the single nodes? Are there better ways?)

Comment: Hm. May be you need bigger nodes (memory problems) or may be you need to review how you are using nodes.
1. If you have a lots of frequent updates - use bulk update. 
2. If you are deleting documents often - consider for soft deletion. 

In normal state you should never have a problem with automatic rolling restarts :)

Comment: How is `priority` mapped?